# Django save on model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I just want that it will automatic compute when it save on the database.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_price = self.price * self.quantity
        return (Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The error I received is:

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return (Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`
To call parent overriden method we use super function
You're just calling method of a tuple which doesn't exist(the method)
It should be
`return super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`